# Curl command not working for Zapier REST hook

Tags: rest, curl, hook, webhooks, zapier

I am making a Zapier App that will contain a basic trigger. I am using REST hook in API configuration. I followed the instructed steps and everything is fine. At the End i get a Webhook URL, when i am creating a Zap.

---

As per my understanding, i will be using this URL to send POST request. So i use curl terminal command.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{ message: 'lemon', id: 'abc', season: 'summerTime' }' https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/7459492/XXXXXX/
```

I get response

```
{"id": "8e5bc4fb-a54c-4860-a22f-8896fadc95a1", "request_id": "5eb3c0c0-9a44-4543-81ba-87cd1a0793b0", "attempt": "5eb3c0c0-9a44-4543-81ba-87cd1a0793b0", "status": "success"}
```

> But nothing happens.

This trigger is suppose to print message and season in some slack channel, i.e Zap i created.
Even in task log, no log is generated.

> PS: when i do the same POST request with POSTMAN application, it works just
>   fine. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong.
>   I am new to these stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing quotes around your keys in the data. Try this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{ "message": "lemon", "id": "abc", "season": "summerTime" }' https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/7459492/XXXXXX/
```

Note that you can "copy as curl" from postman and emulate exactly what it's doing.